# Using GetEvent on a COM object from an Interop library

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, com, com-interop

I have a COM object that is returned via GetType().Invoke(). I can can see the object properties/methods/fields but not the events:

```
object obj = invoker.Invoke("MethodReturnsObject");
foreach (EventInfo i in obj.GetType().GetEvents()) {
    Console.WriteLine(i); // doesn't print anything
}
```

The library in the References has "Embed Interop Types" is set to True. Using the object browser, I can see that the the object does have the events I am interested in and they are declared public. I can also see the events in ildasm.exe inside my Interop library.

Essentially what I am trying to do is to add a new event handler to an object at runtime, after getting its EventInfo and creating a Delegate:

```
EventInfo info = obj.GetType().GetEvent("SomeEvent");
Delegate deleg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(info.EventHandlerType, someMethodInfo);
info.AddEventHandler(obj, deleg);
```

I am compiling and running on two different PCs, could it be the case that the Interop dll is not visible on the other machine? I was under impression that Embed Interop Type handles this problem, or perhaps it is necessary to use regasm/gacutil?

Comment: COM does not support reflection.  How to seems to anyway in some select cases is a very long story.  But that is a very short one for events, that can never work.  You should not be writing code like this when you use the Embed Interop Types feature, you already know the types.  So use them.

Comment: I have a custom GetType with IDispatchInfo that gives me correct com objects, rather than System.__ComObject, so I can use fields/properties etc, but not the events. And that's what I find puzzling. I'd love to use the types directly, but that's not the goal of the app, I need to bind handlers to events without prior knowledge of it's type/delegate params.

Comment: Just an idea, but could you add the COM to a managed library at design time (as a wrapper library) and then dynamically explore the managed interop for the events rather than querying the COM objects directly ?

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange, that's kind of what I'm doing now, all the events have to be listed in a separate class, which I can do a GetEvent() on. But it would be great to get the events dynamically.

Comment: @platforma, I'm playing with a COM object here and it also has events. If I dotPeek the Interop assemblies I see a separate interface definition for the events. So I wonder if it is possible to generate the interop assemblies on the fly and then inspect the managed assemblies for the right information. The once you have those you could then just do standard interop. All good in theory, I have not idea how to do IA generation runtime. I wonder how VS does it?

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange, I'm also using ildasm.exe to look at the interop dissasembly and I can separate event interfaces/delegates. Visual Studio does generate them and if "Embed Interop Types" is set to True, they will be (selectively) embedded into the application assembly. I've had some luck using dynamic on my com objects, but nothing close to actually solving the problem.